# Loop incorreto javaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var contador = 1;
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){
    var form_data = {};
    //form_data["concept"] = $('.payment-form input[name="concept"]').val();
    //form_data["description"] = $('.payment-form input[name="description"]').val();
    form_data["status"] = $('.payment-form #status option:selected').text();
    form_data["amount"] = parseFloat($('.payment-form input[name="amount[]"]').val()).toFixed(2);
    //form_data["date"] = $('.payment-form input[name="date"]').val();
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="ico-cancel"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
        $('<td class="input-'+type+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
        $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto[]").val(form_data["status"]).appendTo(row);
        $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "produto[]").val(form_data["amount"]).appendTo(row);
        contador++;
    });
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row);
    calc_total();
});
```

O problema esta na variável contador, ao invés de ela contar de 1 em 1 como está no código, ao passar pelo loop era soma 3 ao invés de 1, ou seja , ela chega no loop valendo 1 e na próxima iteração vale 4, na próxima 7 e assim sucessivamente, alguém consegue entender o por que?

Comment: o form_data tem 3 elementos, é normal que some ao contador 3 vezes, estás dentro de um foreach. o que significa que vai correr aquele código 3 vezes

Comment: E como eu faço pra resolver isso?

Comment: para que é que queres o contador? não podes usar simplesmente um "form_data.length"?

Comment: Consegui, só retirei o contador e os inputs do loop haha, desculpa a pergunta noob

Comment: É que eu preciso enviar os dados que foram selecionados ao PHP e eu queria separar, produto1=>array()...etc..e como estava dentro do loop, ele enviava os dados os PHP triplicados dai, entende?

Answer (score 0):

`form_data` contém 3 atributos: `status`, `amount`, `remove-row`
`$.each` executa a função uma vez para cada elemento de `form_data`

Por isso, ele está contabilizando 3 vezes.

Se pretende contar o número de clicks com `contador`, precisa deixar `contador++` fora do `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

`each` é uma iteração ao conteudo de uma lista; neste caso, uma iteração ao que está dentro de `form_data` - que tu estás a defenir com 3 coisas: `status`, `amount` e `remove-row`; ora, um `each` o que faz é passar por casa uma dessas propriedades de fazer qualquer coisa.

A razão para a variavél `contador` estar a `4` é porque o `each` iterou pelas `3` propriedades que o `form_data` tinha e somou ao valor inicial da mesma, que era `1`.

Em vez de fazer um `each` (leia-se "a cada item da seguinte lista"), eu acho que tu queres adicionar o que está dentro daquele objecto a um outro elemento. Se for isso, escusas de fazer o `each` e podes logo usar directamente a propriedade:

```
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){
    var formData = {};
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    formData.form = $('.payment-form');

    formData.status = $('#status option:selected',formData.form).text();
    formData.amount = parseFloat($('input[name="amount[]"]',formData.form).val()).toFixed(2);
    formData.removeRow = '<span class="ico-cancel"></span>';

    row.append('<td class="input-status">' + formData.status + '</td>');
    row.append('<td class="input-amount">' + formData.amount + '</td>');
    row.append('<td class="input-remove-row">' + formData.removeRow + '</td>');

    row.append('<input type="hidden" name="produto[status]" value="' + formData.status + '"');
    row.append('<input type="hidden" name="produto[amount]" value="' + formData.amount + '"');

    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row);

});
```